# maven project checkin in svn with local jar

Tags: java, maven, svn, dependency-management, software-distribution

I am working in a application which consume a webservice. I generated the webservice client using axis2codegen. Since it is generated code there are lot of duplicate codes exist. As per suggestion on code review we have to remove it and add it as jar. I created a jar and add to the local repository of the maven. But the problem is how can i check in the locally generateed jar to the svn, so that the user who check the project does not need to add it to the local repository manually as i did it. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Storing the .jar files in subversion isn't really the "maven way".  You might want to consider setting up a corporate maven repository using something like nexus or artifactory and then deploy your .jar artifacts there instead.

Once that's done you can distribute a corporate settings.xml file pointing to this repository (or include it in each projects pom.xml file) and you can then manage your generated code like any other maven dependency.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

**Don't commit jar into SVN**: dependency management has introduced the concept of "artifact repository" separating binaries from sources:

- binary are saved into artifact repository
- source are saved into source code management repository

In order to **share the jar with your pears** you should:

1. install the jar in a corporate maven repository like [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)
2. add a dependency to the jar in your project pom
3. commit the pom into SVN
4. tell to your pears to check out from SVN the updated pom

Comment: How can i find the nexus directory...?

Comment: A corporate maven repository isn't a directory: [look the features](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix), the community support, and the documentation; then choose your repository manager, install it, configure Maven to work with it, and install artifact into it. [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) have good on-line documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. In most circumstances you will use maven to deploy the project (the jar) to a repository manager (Nexus is by far the de facto for this).

Next you configure your co-workers to proxy their maven requests to yuor Nexus installation which itself "knows" about maven Central, thus providing a single point of presence for everything both from the outside world and published internally.

It's usually a good idea for another service such as Jenkins to be paired with a release plugin to execute the maven release procedure on your before, and for it to publish the artefacts too.

Here we have a long list of maven projects that our Jenkins installation builds upon noticing an SVN change. Upon the click of a button within Jenkins for the project, it can perform a complete build and release to our Nexus repository the project's newly built-and-tested artefacts.